# update query using joins in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL and I am facing issue with update with joins or multiple tables. Please see the below codes (A) is not giving output it continuously executes with no results.

And In case of (B) its the same table but it gets update in 4 second.

Why?

Please clarify.

(A)

```
SET  SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
Update MIS_Master_Sheet_New as a,temp_ClientProcess as b 
set a.Client_Process=b.ClientProcess
where  a.CRP_RefNo=b.CRP_RefNo;
```

(B)

```
update MIS_Master_Sheet_New,
(select CRP_RefNo,ClientProcess from temp_ClientProcess ) as Y 
set Client_Process=Y.ClientProcess
where MIS_Master_Sheet_New.CRP_RefNo=Y.CRP_RefNo
```

Thank You Very Much in Advance.